# Problem with list, decimals and thousands separators on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an Excel macro which has to save a data table (columns A to E) on a sheet to a CSV format. How it works: for each line of the table, I iterate over each element to concatenate them with a semicolon separator in a new workbook that I save in CSV format then close (cf the complete macro at the end of my post).

Capture of my Excel file:
[image: Capture of my Excel file]

Since I have users from all around the world, separator settings may vary, so this macro has to force the settings so as:

- List separator = semicolon
- Thousands separator = nothing or comma
- Decimals separator = point

However, I have encountered several issues:

- The CSV format with a semicolon works perfectly fine if the Windows list separator setting is a semicolon, but if it is for example a comma, it is impossible to force the semicolon with the `SaveAs` function => I decided to create "by hand" my CSV file by concatenating the elements with semicolon in the same column. But when saving this column in CSV format, I don't know why, double quotes are put around each line and I can't take them off (I can't search and replace them since they do not appear when the file is opened in Excel).

  The only way I found to avoid that issue is to save the file in text format with the parameter `FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter`.

  If you have any idea why is that, I am all ears (is it because of ASCII norms?)

  ```vb
  For FiltersCount = 1 To Dialog.Filters.Count
      If Dialog.Filters(FiltersCount).Extensions = "*.txt" Then
          Index = FiltersCount
          Exit For
      End If
  Next

  With Dialog
      .FilterIndex = Index
      .Title = "Enregistrer sous... / Save as..."
      .Show

      If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
          Path = .SelectedItems(1)
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
      Else
          MsgBox "Aucun emplacement ou nom n'a été défini. Merci de réessayer!" & Chr(10) & _
                                                                                            "No location or name has been defined. Please retry!"
      End If
  End With
  ```
- My second issue is about decimals and thousands separators. The idea, that theoretically should work, is to change the user settings (not part of the best practices I know..) to force the settings I want ("." = decimals and "," = thousands).

  ```vb
  'Save current separator parameters
  UseSystemSeparators = Application.UseSystemSeparators
  DecimalSeparator = Application.DecimalSeparator
  ThousandsSeparator = Application.ThousandsSeparator

  'Save separator parameters required by Data Management
  Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
  Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
  Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
  ```

  The issue is that if my data is a decimal number, when I copy it in my new workbook, even if the decimal setting has been forced on a point, the point becomes a comma again. So my idea was to search and replace commas with point. But this is where it becomes tricky: according to the user settings, this might conflicts with the thousands separator. I don't understand why the point becomes a comma whereas this is against the settings I have forced and the only way I found to avoid that is to change the thousands separator with a "/" to make sure there is no conflict... but this is not the prettiest and steadiest way to do that I think.

  If anybody has any idea, any leads, it would be so helpful!

Finally, to bring more details, here is my complete macro and a test dataset:

```vb
Sub xlsToCSV()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim UseSystemSeparators As Boolean
    Dim DecimalSeparator As String
    Dim ThousandsSeparator As String
    Dim lastDataRowIndex As Long
    Dim Dialog As FileDialog
    Dim FiltersCount, Index As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, mergedData As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Save current separator parameters
    UseSystemSeparators = Application.UseSystemSeparators
    DecimalSeparator = Application.DecimalSeparator
    ThousandsSeparator = Application.ThousandsSeparator

    'Save separator parameters required by Data Management
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "/"

    lastDataRowIndex = calculateLastRowIndex("B", "C", "D", "E")

    Workbooks.Add

    For i = 2 To lastDataRowIndex
        For j = 1 To 4
            mergedData = mergedData & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) & ";"
        Next
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1) = mergedData & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5)

        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1) = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1), "/", "")
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1) = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1), ",", ".")

        mergedData = Empty
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Save dialog / file forced as CSV
    Set Dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    For FiltersCount = 1 To Dialog.Filters.Count
        If Dialog.Filters(FiltersCount).Extensions = "*.txt" Then
            Index = FiltersCount
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    With Dialog
        .FilterIndex = Index
        .Title = "Enregistrer sous... / Save as..."
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Path = .SelectedItems(1)
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
        Else
            MsgBox "Aucun emplacement ou nom n'a été défini. Merci de réessayer!" & Chr(10) & _
                                                                                            "No location or name has been defined. Please retry!"
        End If
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

errHandler:
    'Restore current separator parameters
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = UseSystemSeparators
    Application.DecimalSeparator = DecimalSeparator
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = ThousandsSeparator

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *Hello everyone  (I was sure I wrote it a the begining of my post, turns out I did not, I promise I am not rude ;) )

Comment: For part of your problem, save the `CSV` as a `CSV` formatted as your region of choice; then instruct your users to **NOT OPEN** the `csv`. Rather they should **IMPORT** the `csv` file and define the `csv` settings at that point.  This process can be automated in **Power Query** or with a **VBA macro** to accomplish the importing task.

Comment: re Thousands separators (or in India 10^3n+2 separators): Store the file without any, and let the local user's formatting present them how they want.

Comment: Ron's suggestion is good.
I would add that you should choose either "Anglo-Saxon" (decimal point, comma as separator) or "Continental" (decimal comma, semi-colon as separator) as the base format that you store - don't create a non-standard mixture.